# input == null when loading an image

Tags: java

I have been trying to load an image, and it works fine in eclipse. However when running it compiled, it crashes with input == null. The method for getting the icon is here:

```
public ImageIcon getIcon(String iconName){
    InputStream imageStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images"+File.separator+iconName);
    InputStream t = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images");

    Image image = null;
    try
    {
        image  = ImageIO.read(imageStream);
        return new ImageIcon(image);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        return null;
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Image folder stream: Im"+t);
        System.out.println("Image folder + image stream: "+imageStream);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The console output is:

```
input == null!
Image folder stream:sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@14b4656e
Image folder + image stream: null
input == null!
Image folder stream:sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@3a81e634
Image folder + image stream: null
```

I have read other threads with the same error as me, but I haven't been able to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Try using a complete path to the image instead of a relative path.

Comment: First, getResourceAsStream() expects `/`-separeted paths. So you shouldn't use File.separator, but `/`. Second, what is the value of iconName, what is the structure of your project, how do you build and run your program, and where is the icon located in that structure?

Comment: Oh wow. replacing File.separator with / fixed it. Thanks for the help, post it as an answer if you want

Comment: An 'absolute' path will probably not fix it if the resource is not on the classpath. Fixing the classpath will. If it isn't on the classpath, just use a FileInputStream!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResource[AsStream]()` expects a `/`-separated path. Always. Whatever your platform is. Don't use `File.separator`. Use `/`.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly a problem with your class path.

The imageStream variable is null, so your classloader is failing to find the file and load it. From there on, the method is destined to fail.

When running in your IDE, Eclipse will helpfully set up paths for you, meaning it will run fine. When you run it on the command line you need to ensure that your classpath matches Eclipse's.

I assume that you have an 'images' folder which contains your various images, but is that available either in your compiled JAR or as an element in your classpath in your run command?

Comment: Yeah I have an images folder, and that was compiling into the jar just fine. However, JB Nizet's response fixed the problem for me, thanks for writing an answer however.